# Is it possible to force a certain amount of numbers in a column in MYSQL WORKBENCH?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL and I decided to work with the GUI platform (Workbench).
I would like to know if it is possible to force a certain quantity of numbers in a column.

I mean, if i want an integer with 4 numbers and they introduce an integer with 3 numbers, i want to block it, as well as if they introduce 5 numbers.

Thank you and sorry for the English.

Comment: The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines - one workaround is to create a trigger another might be to create a numbers table and add a foreign key pointing to this.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood your problem, you are looking for constraints. Yes you can enforce constraints on the fields that you want.

Consider the following relation of `subject_marks`.

Let us say that you have two fields here, namely `SUB_ID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY` and `SUB_MARK INT`. Here, let us assume that the value of the field `SUB_MARK` cannot go beyond 0 and 100. Such a case could be achieved by the following.

```
CREATE TABLE subject_marks(
    SUB_ID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    SUB_MARK INT,
    CHECK (SUB_MARK>=0 AND SUB_MARK<=100)
);
```

If the table is already created, you could alter it to add the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE subject_marks
ADD CHECK (SUB_MARK>=0 AND SUB_MARK<=100)
```

In your specific case, you could achieve this with a check constraint, that checks the value against some math.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_num CHECK (num >= 1000 AND num <= 9999);
```

Answer (score 0):

How can this be done in MYSQL WORKBENCH, the columns do not appear to have a way to add the constraint ADD Check (SUB_MARK >= 0 AND SUB-MARK<=100)

I can see how it can be done after the Table was created outside of WORKBENCH but within WORKBENCH I can not see how it can be done